# installing Eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: linux, eclipse

hey everyone i am trying to install Eclipse helios for C/C++ developers on a ubntu OS

i am new with all this ubntu stuff - even though i downloaded a version of helios from the Eclipse site i have no idea how to install the program

i can't find the eclipse.exe file that it has when is installed it in windows!

thanks allot.

Brad

Comment: Probably better asked on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it using the Ubuntu Software Centre and not through the Eclipse website. Or alternatively, open a terminal by pressing alt + F2 and type `sudo apt-get install eclipse` it might ask for your administrator password and tell you the file size, all you have to do is agree by typing 'y' then it will be installed automatically.

In case you want to use the file that you have downloaded, telling us what kind of file it is would help us give you the necessary instructions. For example it might be a *tarball* or a gzip archive.

Comment: Are the Ubuntu repos now on Helios? Last time I checked they weren't.

Comment: The Ubuntu repos are not up-to-date - the newest version in Ubuntu  is still Eclipse 3.5.2. Using the bundles from eclipse.org works very well.

Comment: hey thanx allot... i am doig as you said.
but will it downnload for me eclipse for C/C++ developers?

Comment: But if they're not yet familiar with Ubuntu, using packages from the Ubuntu repo might be easier to install than using none at all or messing something up. I edited my answer and asked him what kind of file is it that he has downloaded so we could give him the command to extract it in /opt directory and create a link (shortcut) to the desktop.

Comment: this is the file that is downloaded
eclipse-linuxtools-helios-incubation-linux-gtk.tar.gz
i downloaded it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ the last  link on the page for 32 bit

Comment: @arcasuisus Do the repos have the C/C++ version? I think you can download it from within Eclipse, but I don't think it's (easily) possible to use the software manager to get **just** the C/C++ version.

Comment: @stephen yes you're right about that, it will get eclipse core and might include other features that will not be used. 

if it's an issue then you could extract that tarball by opening a terminal window and cd over its directory and type 

sudo tar zxf eclipse-linuxtools-helios-incubation-linux-gtk.tar.gz /opt

Answer (score 2):

There are no exe's on Linux! Simply unzip the version you downloaded (32 or 64 bit), put the new eclipse folder to some location (e.g. /opt), and run /opt/eclipse/eclipse - voilá.
Make sure you have the correct JDK installed (Sun JDK or OpenJDK) in the correct flavour (32/64 bit - depending on the version of eclipse you downloaded).

Comment: Usually better to get the version directly from eclipse.org or one of the sites pointed to there. The Linux distros are typically out of date.